# DNS resolution failure error while connecting to grpc server running on docker

Tags: docker, grpc-dotnet

I am trying to access the grpc server which exposes 9000 port and is running as docker container.

I am using .net core client to connect to the server.It works perfectly fine when GRPC server is not running as a docker container.

I have tried using both the "localhost","dockerconatiner-ip" while creating the channel from client.I am running the grpc server on "0.0.0.0"and port 9000.

docker commands:
docker run -p 9000:9000  -a stdin -a stdout -it

Error:
Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="DNS resolution failed")

dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.0
COPY Sample/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sample.dll"]
```

Service Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GRPC_VERBOSITY", "DEBUG");
            const int Port = 9000;
            Server server = new Server
            {
                Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 9000, ServerCredentials.Insecure) },
                Services = { BindService(new TestService()) }
            };
            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("starting server");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to shut down");
            Console.ReadKey();
            server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Grpc Server stopped");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Test service has a method to print received text to console.

Comment: `1.` Show your docker file, `2.` show your `startup.cs` where you register grpc services

Comment: Is your client also running inside a container? Or is it running locally on your machine?

Comment: It is running locally on my machine

Comment: Try using `host.docker.internal` as the hostname and `9000` as the port